# Primefaces refresh calendar on dialog after action

Tags: java, primefaces

i have one input calendar (now is  but the same occurs with ) inside a one dialog. The problem is when i execute the action, where i call the bean to save the object referenced in this calendar, and then, when i create a new object for this input, the dialog is not refreshed with this new "null value". They apparently keep the state on page of the old object, but in back, on bean, the object is the new.

I dont know what im doing wrong and i will apreciatte if someone could help me.

This is the part of my dialog where i put the input

```
                    <div>
                        <p:outputLabel id="calendarLabel"
                                       value="beginDate"
                                       for="dateInput"/>
                        <ii:calendar id="dateInput"
                                     pattern="yyyy-mm-dd"
                                     value="#{bean.entity.beginDate}"
                                     immediate="true"
                                     style="text-align: right !important;">
                            <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" update="@this"/>
                        </ii:calendar>
                        <p:message id="beginDateMessage"
                                   for="dateInput"/>
                    </div>
```

Here is the button where i call the action that save the object refereced on calendar and create a new object (entity = new Entity() on the end of method called)

```
               <p:commandButton id="CmdYes"
                                 styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes"
                                 icon="fa fa-check"
                                 value="Confirm"
                                 process="@form @form:dialog"
                                 update="@form @form:dialog"
                                 immediate="true"
                                 action="#{bean.persistEntity()}"
                                 onstart="PF('pageBlocker').show();"
                                 onsuccess="PF('dialog').hide();PF('pageBlocker').hide();">
                </p:commandButton>
```

I already tried everything, and the most close solution was create an button using onclick="calendarWidget.setDate(null)". With this i can click the button and clear the calendar input, i could put that in a JS and call the click after the action. But this seens to me a bad solution.

Can someone help me to understand what im doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

This is the action that calls the dialog:

```
                <p:menuitem id="actionSuspend"
                            value="Suspend"
                            process="@form" update="@form" 
                            immediate="true"
                            onstart="PF('pageBlocker').show()"

                            oncomplete="PF('dialog').show();PF('pageBlocker').hide()"
                            actionListener="#{bean.doAction('action', item)}"
                            rendered="#{bean.canDoAction('action', item)}"
                />
```

Comment: The commandButton is within the same dialog of the calendar, right? Can you post the code that opens this dialog, or check if in that point is there the update of the dialog? Another try is with this component: [resetInput](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/resetInput.xhtml), on dialog show

Comment: I update the question with the action that calls the Dialog. Everything is on the same form.

Comment: @MatteoZanini use resetInput work for me! Thank you very much my friend!

Comment: you can add this as answer, so i can mark it solved.

Comment: I can't recreate all your scenario, but you can have a try with Primefaces [resetInput](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/resetInput.xhtml)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@MatteoZanini did solve the problem:

The resetInput works for me, i call it on button that opens the dialog and then, erverything is reseted.

```
               <p:menuitem id="actionSuspend"
                            value="Suspend"
                            process="@form" update="@form" 
                            immediate="true"
                            onstart="PF('pageBlocker').show()"
                            oncomplete="PF('dialog').show();PF('pageBlocker').hide()"
                            actionListener="#{bean.doAction('action', item)}"
                            rendered="#{bean.canDoAction('action', item)}">
               <p:resetInput target="@form:dialog"/>
                        </p:menuitem>
```

Comment: Reset input should not be used for this. It is only for correcting validation errors and then resetting things. Not for clearing after normal submission. You should do that normally in your java code

Comment: As I say before. My object is cleaned in the bean, but I don't know why, I can refresh his actual state.

Comment: There is no bean visible in your code in the question (it is not a [mcve] by a long shot) so we cannot see what is./might actually be wrong

Comment: Thats is what i mean: value="#{bean.entity.beginDate}"

Comment: There is no bean code in your Q, so it is impossible to see what strange things you have in your code for which you think this is **the** solution